# A simple strftime() generates errors in XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

The following line:

```
strftime('%G%m%d%H%M%S', mktime(0, 0, 0, '01', 1, date('Y')));
```

generates the error:

```
Warning: Invalid CRT parameters detected on line...
```

This happens only in XAMPP, not in MAMP.

Any ideas why? I'm thinking it's the format parameter that messes it up. How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Windows. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak.aspx) `%G` is not a valid modifier.

this link is in [php.net docs](https://www.php.net/strftime).

you could do:

```
strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', mktime(0, 0, 0, '01', 1, date('Y')));
```

use `%Y`

Comment: So there's seem to be no real difference between %Y and %G, am I right?